# Stop / terminate rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, generator, terminate

I'm writing an upgrade generator for my gem and I want it to check if my gem is installed. That's not a problem, but if the gem is not installed I want to terminate the rest of the methods.

Here is my code so far:

```
module Baco

  module Generators

    class UpgradeGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

      def check_installation
        unless File.exists?( File.join( destination_root, "config", "initializers", "baco.rb" ) )
          p "Baco not yet installed. Please run 'rails generate baco:install' to install"

          # Here the generator needs to stop everything!
        end
      end

      def next_method
        # We don't want this if the gem is not installed!
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Anybody can point me to the right method to use?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can raise an Error, and that should stop the generator.